# Problema con Python Cogs

Tags: python, discord.py

Tengo problemas al setear COGS en Discord.py

Al ejecutar index.py, hice muchos comandos y eventos en otro index.py unico pero obviamente, no puedo tener todo eso ahí, decidi usar cogs y nunca los he usado ya que no programo mucho en discord.py

El error es el siguiente:

```
local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py:618: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'setup' was never awaited
  setup(self)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 20, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "index.py", line 17, in main
    await load()
  File "index.py", line 13, in load
    await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
    import asyncio
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="+", intents=intents, help_command=None)

async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
 

async def main():
    await load()
    await bot.start("TOKEN")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Y tengo un **Ping.py **en la carpeta **Cogs**

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands

class ping(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        @commands.Cog.listener()
        async def on_ready(self):
            print("Tamo reaaady")

            @commands.Command()
            async def ping(self, ctx):
                await ctx.send("Pong)


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(ping)
```

Comment: Te faltó instanciar el Cog. Es decir, llamar a la clase, hacer bot.add_cog(ping()).

Comment: te refieres en el index? Pq en el ping.py ya esta

Comment: No, me refería a ping.py. En el código que publicaste no está.